# executable with pyinstaller does not work with moviepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, moviepy, python-3.10

I have a script that needs moviepy, I wanted to have it as an executable but that doesn't seem to work, does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

```py
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Console:

```
./run 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "moviepy/editor.py", line 87, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'
[75721] Failed to execute script 'run' due to unhandled exception!
```

## Update

If I comment out the library `VideoFileClip` it works, but I need this module...

I have found a possible solution, but I do not want to edit the library

https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591

Does anyone have a tip what else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

## It works

The solution came from

https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591#issuecomment-965203931

I have only imported the required module, in my case

`from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip`

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a virtual environment using venv.
2. Then create a requirements file, if you haven't done already.

   pip freeze > requirements.txt
3. Use this requirements file in your pyinstaller, while creating executable.

   path\to\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --paths \venv_location\file.py
4. You can go through [PyInstaller Docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#shortening-the-command) for more details.

Comment: That did not work either